# How to fix "InvalidSessionIdException: Tried to run command without establishing a connection" error in RobotFramework?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework, geckodriver

When running a testsuite in RobotFramework 3.1 on the Firefox Browser, the test run fails at `Click Element` Keyword with the following error:

> InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Tried to run command without
>   establishing a connection.

I already tried to put in `Sleep  5 seconds`, just before the `Click Element` Keyword. It still fails. I have no clue what to do.

The tests run on a docker container, that has the following settings/version of the programs, libraries and drivers:

```
ENV PYTHON3_VERSION 3.6.7*
ENV CHROMIUM_VERSION 71.0.*
ENV FIREFOX_VERSION 64.0*
ENV GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION v0.23.0
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.45
ENV PABOT_VERSION 0.45
ENV ROBOT_FRAMEWORK_VERSION 3.1
ENV SELENIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION 3.2.0
ENV ROBOTFRAMEWORK_ROOT_PATH /opt/robotframework
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

The same tests run perfectly on the Chrome browser, as it is a very simple test. It also should be able to easy run the test on the Firefox browser and yet it fails at a simple `Click Element`. 
What can I do to get rid of this error message?

Comment: add your code to question as what you had tried

Comment: Well, it's really just that "Click Element    .//someXpath". That's it.

Comment: You said it fails just before `Click Element`, what is before?

Comment: Your selenium version is too old - for that version of geckodriver you must be running >= 3.11.0; look here - https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html#supported-platforms